# Bash script that remove oldest files recursively from a directory if free size is over a threshold

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm looking for a script that removes files (oldest first) from a directory if the space free on a partition is less than 5%.

I'v found the following script:

```
FILESYSTEM=/dev/sda1 # or whatever filesystem to monitor
CAPACITY=95 # delete if FS is over 95% of usage 
CACHEDIR=/home/user/lotsa_cache_files/

# Proceed if filesystem capacity is over than the value of CAPACITY (using df POSIX syntax)
# using [ instead of [[ for better error handling.
if [ $(df -P $FILESYSTEM | awk '{ gsub("%",""); capacity = $5 }; END { print capacity }') -gt $CAPACITY ]
then
    # lets do some secure removal (if $CACHEDIR is empty or is not a directory find will exit
    # with error which is quite safe for missruns.):
    find "$CACHEDIR" --maxdepth 1 --type f -exec rm -f {} \;
    # remove "maxdepth and type" if you want to do a recursive removal of files and dirs
    find "$CACHEDIR" -exec rm -f {} \;
fi
```

Which as far as I understand removes files from CACHEDIR if the space used on $FILESYSTEM is over $CAPACITY %.

However, I'm not sure if this works but I'm sure it won't the delete the oldest first.

I would like it to remove the minimum number of files (from oldest to newest) in order to free space.

Comment: Not sure about finding the oldest yet but your `if` won't work.  The `awk` statement needs to change a little bit. `awk 'FNR == 2 { gsub(.........` Need to add `FNR == 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script will delete every file in `$CACHEDIR` if /dev/sda1 is more than 95% full. 
Do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY="/path/to/your/directory"
CAPACITY=95
while [[ $(df $DIRECTORY | awk 'NR==2 && gsub("%","") {print$5}') -ge $CAPACITY ]];do
        rm -rf $(find $DIRECTORY -mindepth 1 -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | awk 'NR==1 {print$2}')
done
```

You can run this script on crontab, or do a while loop and daemonize it with systemd so it keep running in the background and delete files every time your partition reaches 95%.

Explaining:

`df $DIRECTORY` tracks the directory partition and print it's information.
`awk 'NR==2 && gsub("%","") {print$5}'` print the second line (relevant one, first is heading), remove the percent sign and print the column 5 ("Use%" column).
`rm -rf` removes the result of the following command.
`find $DIRECTORY -mindepth 1 -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | awk 'NR==1 {print$2}'` find the `$DIRECTORY` and print the modify date of the files, then `sort` it and print only second field (filename) of the first line (oldest one).

Comment: Marcos, thanks for your proposal. What's NR==2 ? I mean, what syntax is that, i what language?

Comment: BTW, if DIRECTORY doesn't exists. Wouldn't it start deleting files from the current directory?

Comment: THanks Marcos. What about mindepth 1, why is it there? What happens if script doesn't have access to remove some files? Would it hang in an infinite loop?

Comment: NR is awk syntax for the Number of Records (lines) processed by awk. In this case, it is printing the second (NR==2) line. See explanation. In this script it will print the fifth field of the second line, which is the "Use%" in df. And about the DIRECTORY variable, you must specify a valid directory, otherwise it will delete files from current directory. You could enhance it like this: if [[ -z $DIRECTORY ]] || [[ ! -d $DIRECTORY ]];then echo "specify a valid directory"; exit 1;fi

Comment: Wow, that sounds dangerous, deleting other files than the ones in the directory.

Comment: -mindepth is a find parameter for the minimum amount of subdirs it will find. With -mintdepth 1 it will not print "." (current directory) nor ".." (parent directory) but will print everything else. You must run it with a user that has rw access to the directory.

Comment: If the directory is deleted after the IF it would still delete other files?

Comment: That "if" will test if the DIRECTORY variable is set and if it is a valid directory, you must place it at the start of the script. then if the variable is unset or if it is not a valid directory, it will exit. Otherwise it will run the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0):

How about using ls to get the file to delete?

```
FILESYSTEM=/dev/sda1 # or whatever filesystem to monitor
CAPACITY=95 # delete if FS is over 95% of usage 
CACHEDIR=/home/user/lotsa_cache_files/

# Proceed if filesystem capacity is over than the value of CAPACITY (using df POSIX syntax)
# using [ instead of [[ for better error handling.
if [ $(df -P $FILESYSTEM | awk '{ gsub("%",""); capacity = $5 }; END { print capacity }') -gt $CAPACITY ]
then
    # Remove the oldest file in CACHEDIR:
    # rm $CACHEDIR/$( ls -t $CACHEDIR | tail -1 )
    rm $CACHEDIR/$( ls -tp $CACHEDIR | sed '/\/$/d' | tail -1 )
fi
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to exclude directories when using **ls**. Also, I believe you might get multiple files per line with your command.

Comment: On the first point, you are right, and I have added a filter for that.  But no, you will not get multiple files per line.  The `ls` command recognizes when the output is a not a console (because it needs to know how many columns the terminal has), and just prints one per line.